# Inicialização de serviços em container docker

Tags: docker

estou com o seguinte problema:

Tenho uma imagem Docker do Ubuntu com o OpenSSH-Server instalado e funcionando normalmente.

Criei uma imagem do Wildfly, tal criação usou como base a imagem do Ubuntu com o OpenSSH-Server instalado, porém ao iniciar o Wildfly, o SSH não é iniciado.

Minha dúvida: Tenho que iniciar o SSH no Dockerfile do Wildfly, ou a iniciação do SSH só precisar estar no Dockerfile do Ubuntu?

Comment: Resolveu sua dúvida a partir de outra fonte? Seria bom responder você mesmo neste caso. Ou a dúvida permanece?

Comment: Obrigado por me lembrar @Murrillo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver o meu problema utilizando o "supervisord" nas minhas imagens. Vocês poderão entrar as configurações no meu Docker Hub: https://hub.docker.com/r/marcosoliveirasoares94/